# How do i search a web-page's HTML for a URL(s) that contains a specific word using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Using Python I would like to be able to create a list of URLs that I have taken from multiple pages, each page having a single link (although there may be multiple references on the page to the same link) with a keyword that is repeated in each of the URLs. 
How do I search the page's HTML for the URL that contains this particular word?

Apologies if this is something really obvious, any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Also you have the list of URLs already, or are you looking for how to build it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the BeautifulSoup library is what you're looking for. This is one of the most popular libraries for web scraping in Python. You can find the project page here: https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

You'll first need to get the HTML data of the page that you're scraping, which can be done using a library such as requests or urllib. In my sample code below, I'm using the requests library.

After getting the HTML data of the page, you can instantiate a BeautifulSoup object, use the find_all method passing "a" as an argument to specify that you're looking for URLs (because <a> tags in HTML signify a hyperlink), and then perform a membership test on the the href (hyperreference) of each found URL to test whether or not a specific word is in the href associated with the URL.

```py
import bs4
import requests

# Get the HTML data from the web page.
html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/").content

# Instantiate a BeautifulSoup object based on the HTML data.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Creating a list to store results in.
urlsContainingWord = []

# Get all the URLs in the page containing the word.
for url in soup.find_all("a"):
    if "mail" in url["href"]:
        urlsContainingWord.append(url)

# Print out the result.
print(urlsContainingWord)
```

In this example, I'm looking for all URLs containing the word "mail" on google.com. My output looks like this:

```
[<a class="gb1" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a>]
```

Alternatively, if you just want the hrefs themselves, then you can loop through your list and refer to only the href of each found URL.

```py
for url in urlsContainingWord:
    print(url["href"])
```

Output:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
```